# Why are overloaded inherited static functions ambiguous?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-methods

this is what I tried (the functions "fun" must be static):

```
#include<iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        static void fun(double x) { std::cout << "double" << std::endl; }
};

class B
{
    public: 
        static void fun(int y) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
};

class C
:
    public A,
    public B
{
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    double x = 1; 
    int y = 1; 

    C::fun(x); 
    C::fun(y); 

    return 0;
}
```

and using g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease), I got the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
main.cpp:27:5: error: reference to 'fun' is ambiguous
     C::fun(x); 
     ^
main.cpp:12:21: note: candidates are: static void B::fun(int)
         static void fun(int y) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
                     ^
main.cpp:6:21: note:                 static void A::fun(double)
         static void fun(double x) { std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
```

So my question is: how come in C++ if I can override [member functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/overload_member_fn_base_derived.htm), and not static functions? Why isn't overloading is not working in this scenario? I would expect the compiler to bring "fun" into the namespace C:: and then do name mangling and use overloading to distinguish C::fun(int) and C::fun(double).

Comment: This is not because the functions are static, but because of your class hierarchy. Remove the 'static` keyword, and there will be no difference.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: they have to be static, no chance in making them member functions, I'm dealing with legacy code.

Comment: @tomislav-maric: The ambiguity doesn't go away when the functions aren't static.

Comment: @tomislav-maric, I understand, I was just saying that the functions being `static` is not the source of your problem

Comment: static: all clear, thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason behind this feature in C++?

Comment: Overload resolution happens after name lookup. The compiler cannot find `fun` inside of `C` so it looks up the name in both base classes and finds two `fun` which is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put them into scope yourself:

```
class C
:
    public A,
    public B
{
public:
    using A::fun;
    using B::fun;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is in `class C`'s definition:

```
public:
    using A::fun;
    using B::fun;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what `fun()` method you want to call, therefore you must specify which one you want:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   double x = 1; 
   int y = 1; 

   A::fun(x); 
   B::fun(y); 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The goal of this question is the detection of int vs double. This workaround does not solve the autodetection.